# Can plants be pathogenic towards humans?

Tags: botany, pathology

In googling this question you’ll only find articles about plant pathogens jumping over to humans eg candida auris and pseudomonas aeruginosa.

My question is, like fungi can be infectious to humans (aspergillus, candida, tinea corporis), could a plant infect us?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes: [Protothecosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protothecosis) is infection of the bloodstream by a genus of non-green algae. There are also odd reports of infection by green algae, such as [this one](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/6858958/).